# Houd CI Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'

Tags: node.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bisir.png)I am getting this error from the houd bot
Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'